# Can I add a custom widget to Salesforce Service Cloud Console?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I need to have a custom widget on Salesforce Service Cloud Console. I don't really care where it is as long as it's easily accessible (kind of like the Softphone widget).

I need this for two reasons:

1. I need a quick way for users to change their "status" (a custom field on user).
2. I need to execute some custom javascript to hide certain elements from some page layouts.

Any idea if this can be done?

Note: when I say "Service Cloud Console" I mean this kind of console:
[image: service cloud console screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I think [Custom Console Components](http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/console2_components_overview.htm) may be what you are looking for? ([Here](http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/console2_components_create_app.htm) is how to add them to the console once you made them. Note that after the 11 steps, it says 'Before you can access ...'.)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar thing using a custom console component , there you can add a visual-force page and add a button on it "Change Status". Once user clicks it get who is the logged in user .
`String userid = UserInfo.getUserId()` 
rest is the simple logic to change the status on User record on the page controller.